# Using GDB to change a for loop condition?

Tags: c, loops, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug a program and am interested in the line for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
and want to change i <10 to i<=10 in the GDB debugger. I've used print to change variable names, but how do I do it for this? Thank you.

Comment: gdb cant change your code, it is set to read only...

Comment: I agree: I think there are some tools that allow you to actually *replace* code within the debugger (Visual Studio?)  ... but I doubt that gdb can do this.

Comment: I guess, you can alter registers to flip the jump condition...

Comment: Well, it's a bit dubious.  In this case, where probably only a jump condition gets changed, maybe..

Comment: Move (by editing the code) the `10` into a variable, then edit the variable to `11` by gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> want to change i <10 to i<=10 in the GDB debugger.

There are few ways to do this, depending on *exactly* what you need.

I'll assume that you simply need to do this once, that your binary is built without optimizations, on `x86_64`.

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}

gcc -g -std=c99 t.c && gdb -q ./a.out

gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>:     movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053c <+15>:    jmp    0x400556 <main+41>
   0x000000000040053e <+17>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400541 <+20>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000000000400543 <+22>:    mov    $0x4005f4,%edi
   0x0000000000400548 <+27>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040054d <+32>:    callq  0x400410 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400552 <+37>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400556 <+41>:    cmpl   $0x9,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040055a <+45>:    jle    0x40053e <main+17>
   0x000000000040055c <+47>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400561 <+52>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400562 <+53>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Here you can see that the instruction at address `0x400556` compares value of `i` (stored on stack in location `$rbp-4`) with constant `9`, and jumps back if the value is less than or equal to `9`.

So you can set a breakpoint on instruction at `0x40055a`, and then *force* the jump to be taken even when the compiled code says it shouldn't be:

```
(gdb) b *0x40055a if i == 10
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40055a: file t.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040055a in main () at t.c:4
4             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
(gdb) p i
$1 = 10
(gdb) jump *0x40053e
Continuing at 0x40053e.
10
[Inferior 1 (process 22210) exited normally]
```

Voila: we've printed an extra value.

Another possible approach: set a breakpoint on instruction at `0x400556`, adjust the value of `i` to `i-1`, single-step, adjust the value of `i` to `i+1`, continue.

Yet another approach: binary patch the instruction at `0x400556` to compare with constant `10` instead of `9`:

```
(gdb) disas/r 0x400556,0x400557
Dump of assembler code from 0x400556 to 0x400557:
   0x0000000000400556 <main+41>:        83 7d fc 09     cmpl   $0x9,-0x4(%rbp)
End of assembler dump.
```

Here you can see that the constant `9` is part of the instruction bytes, in particular the byte at address `0x400559`. You can change that byte:

```
(gdb) start

Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:4
4             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Let's overwrite the instruction and disassemble again:

```
(gdb) set *(char*)0x400559 = 10
(gdb) disas/r 0x400556,0x400557
Dump of assembler code from 0x400556 to 0x400557:
   0x0000000000400556 <main+41>:        83 7d fc 0a     cmpl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
End of assembler dump.
```

Looks good: we now compare to `10` instead of `9`. Does it work?

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[Inferior 1 (process 23131) exited normally]
```

Yes, it does!

P.S. Binary-patching the instruction is equivalent to editing the source and rebuilding the binary, except the patch is "forgotten" on next `run`.